# Calendar Extender works only in the first row of GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a `GridView` in which I have textboxes with calendar extendar. I am facing a strange problem.. The calendar extender works ok for the first row of the `GridView` but it does not work.

**ASPX CODE is as below:(sorry, I know it's a long code.)**

```
<asp:TabContainer AutoPostBack="false" ID="TabContainer_Main" Height="270px" runat="server">
<asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel__TravelLine" runat="server" HeaderText="Travel Line">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="div_TravelLine">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel_TravelLine" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_TravelLine" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="grvTravelLine" CssClass="tabledata" runat="server" ShowFooter="True"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="grvTravelLine_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From City">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Eval("From_City") %>' onkeypress="return Alpha(event);"
ID="txtFrmCity_TravelLine" Width="70px" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To City">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtToCity_TravelLine" Text='<%# Eval("To_City") %>' onkeypress="return Alpha(event);"
MaxLength="50" Width="70px" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Travel Mode">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTravelMode_TravelLine" Width="100px" CssClass="drpdown"
runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Travel Date">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTravelDt_TravelLine" Text='<%# Eval("TravelDt") %>' Width="70px"
runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="FormText"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender
ID="Cal_txtTravelDt" CssClass="MyCalendar" runat="server" Format="yyyy/MM/dd"
TargetControlID="txtTravelDt_TravelLine">
</asp:CalendarExtender>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Booking Date">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBookingDt_TravelLine" Text='<%# Eval("BookingDt") %>' runat="server"
ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="FormText"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender ID="Cal_txtBookingDt"
CssClass="MyCalendar" runat="server" Format="yyyy/MM/dd" TargetControlID="txtBookingDt_TravelLine">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Arrival Date">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtArrivalDt_TravelLine" Text='<%# Eval("ArrivalDt") %>' runat="server"
ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="FormText"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender ID="Cal_txtArrivalDt"
CssClass="MyCalendar" runat="server" Format="yyyy/MM/dd" TargetControlID="txtArrivalDt_TravelLine">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount_TravelLine" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtAmount_TravelLine_OnTextChanged"
Text='<%# Eval("Amount") %>' MaxLength="7" Width="200px" onblur="Fixed(this);"
CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbetxtAmount_TravelLine"
runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAmount_TravelLine" FilterMode="ValidChars"
FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="0123456789.">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel" runat="server" OnCommand="DeleteRowHandler_TravelLine"
Text="D"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<br />
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="left">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkAddTravelLineToGrv" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#3366FF"
OnClick="LnkAddTravelLineToGrv_Click">Click To Add</asp:LinkButton><b>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
(Note: D = Delete) </b>
</td>
<td align="right">
<b>Grand Total:&nbsp;&nbsp; </b>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtgrandtotal" Style="text-align: right;" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
CssClass="FormText" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="LnkAddTravelLineToGrv" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
<asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel_LodgingNLiving" runat="server" HeaderText="Lodging & living">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="div_LodgingNLiving">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpPanel_LodgingNLiving" runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkAddLodgingLivingToGrv" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_LodgingLiving" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="grvLodgingLiving" OnRowDataBound="grvLodgingLiving_RowDataBound"
CssClass="tabledata" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="100%">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' onkeypress="return Alpha(event);"
ID="txtCity_LodgingNLiving" Width="80px" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lodging Nights">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Lodging_Nights") %>' ID="txtLodgingNights_LodgingNLiving"
onkeypress="return OnlyNum(event);" Width="50px" MaxLength="3" CssClass="txtbox"
runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Lodging Days">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Lodging_Days") %>' ID="txtLodgingDays_LodgingNLiving"
onkeypress="return OnlyNum(event);" Width="50px" MaxLength="3" CssClass="txtbox"
runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hotel/Lodge Name">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Hotel_LodgeName") %>' MaxLength="50" onkeypress="return Alpha(event);"
ID="txtHotelLodgename_LodgingNLiving" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check-In Date">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("CheckInDt") %>' ID="txtCheckinDt_LodgingNLiving" runat="server"
ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="FormText"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender ID="Cal_txtCheckinDt_LodgingNLiving"
CssClass="MyCalendar" runat="server" Format="yyyy/MM/dd" TargetControlID="txtCheckinDt_LodgingNLiving" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check-Out Date">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("CheckOutDt") %>' ID="txtCheckoutDt_LodgingNLiving" runat="server"
ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="FormText"></asp:TextBox><asp:CalendarExtender ID="CaltxtCheckoutDt_LodgingNLiving"
CssClass="MyCalendar" runat="server" Format="yyyy/MM/dd" TargetControlID="txtCheckoutDt_LodgingNLiving" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remark">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Remark") %>' CssClass="txtbox" ID="txtRemark_LodgingNLiving"
runat="server" Height="50px" Width="80px" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Amount") %>' AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtAmount_LodgingNLiving_OnTextChanged"
MaxLength="7" ID="txtAmount_LodgingNLiving" Width="70px" onblur="Fixed(this);"
CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="Ftb_txtAmount_LodgingNLiving"
runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAmount_LodgingNLiving" FilterMode="ValidChars"
FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="0123456789.">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel" runat="server" OnCommand="DeleteRowHandler_LodgingLiving"
Text="D"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<br />
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="left">
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAddLodgingLivingToGrv" OnClick="LnkAddLodgingLivingToGrv_Click"
runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#3366FF">Click To Add</asp:LinkButton><b>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
(Note: D = Delete) </b>
</td>
<td align="right">
<b>Grand Total:&nbsp;&nbsp; </b>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGrandTotal_LodgingLiving" Style="text-align: right;" runat="server"
ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="FormText" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
<asp:TabPanel ID="TabPanel_IncidentalCost" runat="server" HeaderText="Incidental Cost">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="div_IncidentalCost">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpPanel_IncidentalCost" runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LnkAddIncidentalCostToGrid" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel_IncidentalCost" runat="server">
<asp:GridView ID="grvIncidentalCost" OnRowDataBound="grvIncidentalCost_RowDataBound"
CssClass="tabledata" runat="server" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" Width="100%">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Place">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="50" Text='<%# Eval("Place") %>' onkeypress="return Alpha(event);"
ID="txtPlace_IncidentalCost" Width="200px" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount_IncidentalCost" MaxLength="7" Text='<%# Eval("Amount") %>'
Width="200px" onblur="Fixed(this);" CssClass="txtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender
ID="Ftb_txtAmount_IncidentalCost" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAmount_IncidentalCost"
FilterMode="ValidChars" FilterType="Custom" ValidChars="0123456789.">
</asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remark">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox CssClass="txtbox" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtRemark_IncidentalCost_OnTextChanged"
Text='<%# Eval("Remark") %>' ID="txtRemark_IncidentalCost" runat="server" Height="50px"
TextMode="MultiLine" Width="463px" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="D">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDel" runat="server" OnCommand="DeleteRowHandler_IncidentalCost"
Text="D"></asp:LinkButton></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<br />
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align="left">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LnkAddIncidentalCostToGrid" runat="server" 
Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#3366FF"
OnClick="LnkAddIncidentalCostToGrid_Click">
 Click To Add</asp:LinkButton> 
 <b>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
 &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
(Note: D = Delete) </b>
</td>
<td align="right">
<b>Grand Total:&nbsp;&nbsp; </b>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGrandTotal_IncidentalCost"
 Style="text-align: right;" runat="server"
ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="FormText" Width="80px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

Comment: Question clearly stating the problem...If you could read it carefully it states what OP is asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your `ClientIDMode` property on `Textboxes`

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```

You need to remove abvoe attribute from your `GridView` code, because if you use it, all your `TextBox` controls will have the same ID, "txtCheckoutDt_LodgingNLiving" for this particular control on it calender extender is set. The CalendarExtender controls will find the first value (which is on the first row) and will be all mapped to it.

If you want to refine the patterns of your control ID assignment, [here's](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2010/May/04/Whats-New-in-ASPNET-40-Part-Two-WebForms-and-Visual-Studio-Enhancements) more about the topic.